Permission Denied while creating a new csv file
Code:
@dataclass
class DataIngestionConfig:
    train_data_path:str = os.path.join("artifacts/train_data")
    test_data_path:str = os.path.join("artifacts/test_data")
    raw_data_path:str = os.path.join('artifacts','raw.csv')
# permission denied on this address     ^

class DataIngestionPhase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataIngestionConfig = DataIngestionConfig

    def dataIngestion(self):
        mlflow_logs = Mlflow_logs()
        with mlflow.start_run():
            logging.info("Data Ingestion Phase Start")
            mlflow_logs.log_msg("Data Ingestion Phase Start")
            try:
                df = pd.read_csv("notebooks/data/Dataset.csv")
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(self.dataIngestionConfig.raw_data_path), exist_ok=True)
                df.to_csv(self.dataIngestionConfig.raw_data_path, index=False)
            except Exception as e:
                mlflow_logs.log_msg(f"Exception : {e}")
                raise CustomException(e,sys)

Output :
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'artifacts\\raw.csv']

I tried reading from a csv file and then storing it to a new csv file inside artifacts folder as raw.csv. Folder Permissions have already been granted yet I'm getting this error.

Does this answer your question? PermissionError: Permission denied to reading CSV File in Python

No, in my case, the file isn't open anywhere else. Moreover I've granted full access to this directory

Please note that when running that code above, you don't get that error but NameError: name 'dataclass' is not defined. Please, next time, first extract a [mcve] from your code which you then post here, it would also have shown you that this has nothing to do with machine learning or CSV files. Perhaps, reducing the code would even have enabled you to spot the error yourself.

In os.makedirs you are creating a folder named 'raw.csv' inside 'artifacts'
raw_folder_path = 'artifacts'
os.makedirs(raw_folder_path, exist_ok=True)
df.to_csv(os.path.join(raw_folder_path, 'raw.csv'), index=False)

